# dataframe overridden within for-loop in r

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, recommendation-engine

I have dataset containing million observations from dataset i'm taking 10000 observations. Here is link to dataset file: [dataset file link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12UY1SvDvbu7sFfeM6qFwuzjWDE33IGGr)

```
itemRatingData = itemRatingData[1:10000,]
#V2 is user ID, V1 is item ID, V3 is item rating from use

library(plyr)
countUser = count(itemRatingData, vars = "V2")
#counted the total obeservation per user in dataset

list_of_total_Users = as.list(countUser$V2)
#taking out total number of users as a list
```

next thing i want to do is to extract those users observation who have rated 10 items minimum and i successfully did that. now i have such users who have rated 50, 100 and 1000+ items but i only need 10 observation from users who have minimum rated 10+ items. i did what comes to mind to get desired results:

```
for (i in 1:length(list_of_total_Users)) {
    occurencePerID = subset(itemRatingData, 
    itemRatingData$V2%in%list_of_total_Users[[i]])

    countOccurencePerID = count(occurencePerID, vars = "V2")
    if(countOccurencePerID$freq >= 10){
       newItemRatingData = occurencePerID[1:10,]
    }
}
```

in this code i'm subsetting total observations per user id and then counted them. if user id frequency >= 10 then extract first 10 observations. now the problem i'm facing is every time loop iterate it overwrite the newItemRatingData.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not use images to supply data. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and the first part of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: added link to dataset file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved my issue and solution is:

```
newItemRatingData = data.frame("V2" = numeric(0), "V1" = numeric(0), "V3" = integer(0))

for (i in 1:length(list_of_total_Users)) {
  occurencePerID = subset(itemRatingData, itemRatingData$V2%in%list_of_total_Users[[i]])

  countOccurencePerID = count(occurencePerID, vars = "V2")
  if(countOccurencePerID$freq >= 10){
     newItemRatingData = rbind(newItemRatingData,occurencePerID[1:10,])  
 }
}
```

as for @fino answer that answer was binding column wise dataframe. solution that i find binding dataframe row wise

Answer (score 0):

Even though I can't reproduce your issue without the data it seems like you are replacing the results in `newItemRatingData` every iteration. If you use `cbind()` you can append your rows to `newItemRatingData` withour replacing what's already there

```
newItemRatingData = data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(list_of_total_Users)) {
    occurencePerID = subset(itemRatingData, 
    itemRatingData$V2%in%list_of_total_Users[[i]])

    countOccurencePerID = count(occurencePerID, vars = "V2")
    if(countOccurencePerID$freq >= 10){
       newItemRatingData = cbind(newItemRatingData,occurencePerID[1:10,])
    }
}
```

Comment: getting this error: "Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 10"  ....further added dataset file, here is link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=12UY1SvDvbu7sFfeM6qFwuzjWDE33IGGr